# Why does my Java PriorityQueue behave strange

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, comparator

I plan to use PriorityQueue as a min heap for 5 elements, each element is a tuple declared as following:

```
 public class Tuple implements Comparator<Tuple> {
    public final int x;
    public final double y;

    public Tuple(int x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Tuple() {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Tuple o1, Tuple o2) {
        return (int) (o1.y - o2.y);
    }
}
```

Then, I declare my heap as

```
 PriorityQueue<Tuple> heap = new PriorityQueue<Tuple>(5, new Tuple());
 int capacity = 5;
```

Then, I add element with following code:

```
 if (capacity != 0) {
            if (score > 0) {
                Tuple tmp = new Tuple(i, score);
                heap.add(tmp);
                capacity -= 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (score > heap.peek().y) {
                OutPutPriorityQueue(heap);
                Tuple tmp = new Tuple(i, score);
                heap.remove();
                heap.add(tmp);
                OutPutPriorityQueue(heap);
            }
        }
```

in which, `score` is a `double` calculated elsewhere and `OutPutPriorityQueue` is declared as following:

```
 public void OutPutPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue<Tuple> heap){
    Tuple [] temp = new Tuple[5];
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        temp[i] = heap.poll();
        System.out.print(temp[i].y+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        heap.add(temp[i]);
    }
}
```

Sorry that I have listed too much codes here, but this is the first time I use PriorityQueue, I am not sure where it goes wrong and the logistic of code should be simple enough.

Then my problem is that, the output of my function `OutPutPriorityQueue`, which is supposed to print elements according to an order, print the elements in basically an arbitrary way, here is some sample:

```
 0.5549890273805606 0.6479515952918626  0.8593378488473195  0.53232731034541    1.0
 1.0    0.8593378488473195  0.53232731034541    0.8593378488473195  0.6479515952918626
 1.0    0.6479515952918626  0.8593378488473195  0.53232731034541    0.8593378488473195
 0.8593378488473195 1.6093378488473196  0.53232731034541    0.8593378488473195  0.6479515952918626 
 0.8593378488473195 0.6479515952918626  0.8593378488473195  0.53232731034541    1.6093378488473196
 1.6093378488473196 1.28601715282334    0.53232731034541    0.8593378488473195  0.6479515952918626
```

These numbers are difficult to read, but its behaviors can be summarized as following:

1. every `remove()` and `add()` remove the head one, move the 5th one to head and insert a new one at second place.
2. line `2n-1` should be exactly the same as line `2n`, but they are different. the 2nd one (newest one) is swapped with 5th one
3. it seems that there is no order defined in this queue, but I do define a `compare()` and pass it in.

I have no idea why this is happening, I hope someone can help me.
Do I use `compare()` correctly? or something else?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Read up on [binary heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), that's how `PriorityQueue` is implemented.

Comment: Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis, but that just makes my heap behave even more strange, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you post a full working example so I can reproduce exactly what you have to explain it?

Comment: Hi @SotiriosDelimanolis, if you mean the code, please have a look here: https://github.com/HaohanWang/ActiveLearningForP53/blob/master/src/activeLearner/ActiveLearner.java

Comment: please let me know if you need more, because I don't understand what working example means, sorry about that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I am trying other methods now, relevant codes are from Line 108 to Line 165

Comment: I'll take a look later. A working example is cutting down and posting the code that we could use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: For future questions I would recommend that you organize the question a bit differently. 

The code you posted is not a complete compact example. If you can't post a small example you should post a brief code segment and restate what you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting into the specifics of your queue the first thing I would do is change the comparator. Stay away from the cast and use the comparator supplied with Double.

```
public static int compare(double d1, double d2)
```

From the API: Returns - the value 0 if d1 is numerically equal to d2; a value less than 0 if d1 is numerically less than d2; and a value greater than 0 if d1 is numerically greater than d2.

The compare you have is error prone at bets may be causing an issue for you.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good catch, but I have two points, (1). When I use a `LinkedList<Tuple>` and use `Collections.sort()`, the `compare` works fine. However, I still want to try you solution,  (2). But sorry that I have no idea how to use `static` function in my override `compare`. I can neither change my `compare` to `static` nor initialize a `Comparator` :-(.

Comment: I understand, you would do the following:

 `@Override
 public int compare(Tuple  o1, Tuple  o2) {
  return Double.compare(o1.y, o2.y);
 }`

Comment: Thank you anyway, but unfortunately... the codes behave basically the same...:-(

Comment: Unfortunately the Comparator is only one problem. You have not provided a working example per the request of Sotirios so we can not provide more complete answers. I looked at the github and it references third part libraries and is not a good working example.

Comment: With respect to the comparator, the fact that you are using doubles that by chance return the same order in comparison does not validate your approach. In fact if you sorted using your comparator with the int cast it would give a different sort order than java's native implementation. Try to sort with the following three doubles, 4.5d,4.23d and 5.21d. Your sort will fail if the goal is to sort in a natural order.

I just wanted to point out one problem based on the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. As to question, I will try to ask in a more useful way in the future. I am still learning to use StackOverflow.

Comment: I have done this problem with other implementations days ago. Then, today I write some other codes to compare the difference from my compare and yours. You are absolutely correct. Thank you.